# Class groups and zeta functions for maximal orders in CSAs

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, zeta-functions, noncommutative-rings, picard-group

I'm looking for references for certain algebraic objects in the context of maximal orders in (finite dimensional) central simple algebras over algebraic number fields. Does anyone know of any good references for the state of the art of:

$\bullet$ Picard groups of maximal orders (after Frohlich's work in this [paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1973-180-00/S0002-9947-1973-0318204-3/S0002-9947-1973-0318204-3.pdf));

$\bullet$ Narrow ray class groups of maximal orders (ray class groups are discussed in [Reiner](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/maximal-orders-9780198526735?cc=gb&lang=en&), but I can't find further/more recent discussion anywhere);

$\bullet$ And finally, the Dedekind zeta function for maximal orders (I am aware of [Reiner](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01162247) and [Bushnell](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01159955)'s [work](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0092491) ).